# Rails test to incorporate controller before action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following rails, via devise, registration controller runs successfully

```
before_action :clean_params, only: [:create, :update]
```

defined as:

```
def clean_params
  if !params[:user][:mobile].nil?
    params[:user][:mobile] = params[:user][:mobile].gsub(/\s+/, "")
  end
end
```

However if I run a test

```
mobile = ' 3331 11 220 0 '
user = User.new(first_name: 'MeMeMeMeMe', last_name: 'mYSELF', mobile: mobile, password: '11111111', password_confirmation: '11111111' )
assert user.valid?
user.save!
puts user.mobile
assert user.mobile == '3331112200'
```

it fails, putting  `3331 11 220 0` and thus visibly not running the before_action.

How can one ensure that `before_actions` are run in a test suite?

Comment: Don't use a callback for this. Create a custom setter method in the model that normalizes the values instead. Its got far less moving parts and timing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your test for User class only, but before_action defined for the controller.
If you want to test the result of 'clean_params' you have to create a test for the controller